# CSV Help | Text Delimiter | Use of LibreOffice

Tags: csv, text, spreadsheet, delimiter, libreoffice

I need help with something I'm not quite sure on how to do. Here in the image are data fields (i.e. age) and their values (i.e. 62)
I was wondering how to take age and turn it into a column category and the age values as column entries?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMRUY.png)

Comment: Instead of posting an image, can you give a simple example?  From what I can tell, the cell in question is `N2`, so maybe it would be enough to post its contents.  See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

From the image, it looks like after the import there will be a string in cell `N2` that starts with `{"age":"62"`.  Find an empty column in the spreadsheet and enter "age" in the first row.  In the second row, enter the following formula.

```
=MID(N2,9,2)
```

This produces `62`.  See [MID](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Text_Functions#MID) for documentation.